# Why the value get changes whenever I use "if" statement separately and when use "if" inside "if"?

Tags: arrays, c

When I use the if statement(commented in this code) the "flag" value get stuck at 5 but I got accurate output when I use that "if" inside "if"(as shown in this code).

```
//THIS CODE IS FOR COUNTING THE OCCURENCE OF ANY SPECIFIC ELEMENT.

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
 {
int num[20], count, find;
int key = 0, flag;

printf("ENTER YOUR INPUT LIMIT:\n");
scanf("%d", &count);

printf("ENTER YOUR NUMBERS:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
}

printf("ENTER THE NUMBER YOU WANT TO SEARCH:\n");
scanf("%d", &find);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (find == num[i])
    {
        key++;   //COUNTING TOTAL NO OF OCCURENCE

        if (key == 1)  //RESERVING FIRST POSITION OF ITS OCCURENCE
        {
            flag = i;
        }
    }
    //   if (key == 1)
    //     {
    //         flag = i;
    //     }
}

if (key == 1)
{
    printf("%d is at %d position from starting\n", find, flag + 1);
}
if (key > 1)
{
    printf("%d occurs %d times and the first position of its occurence is %d \n", find, key, flag + 
1);
}
if (key == 0)
{
    printf("NOT FOUND\n");
}

return (0);
}
```

Example output where the value is stuck at 5:
[image: example output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because after the first occurance of the number is found, `key` became `1`, so in that and all of the following iteration the (currently) commented `if` would execute since `key == 1` is `true`. This way overwriting `flag` repeatedly. As soon as another occurance is found and `key` became greater than 1, then `flag` will be left alone at long last. Holding the index before the second occurance. If there is no second occurance of the value, then it will hold the index of the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Using the commented out if statement, the flag value would be the position one before the second occurrence. This is because you'll enter this if statement multiple times, between the first and second occurrence.